# macports dependency: upgrade all packages not depending on a specific port

Tags: upgrade, macports, osx-mavericks, dependencies

I have upgraded to Maverick

when I run:

```
sudo port upgrade outdated
```

I get the error:

```
Error: eigen does not build on Mavericks or later.
```

I have plenty of ports that does not depend on eigen, how do i figure out which ones they are and how do I update them?
For example:

```
sudo port install pypy
```

upgraded pypy to the newest version, but `sudo port upgrade outdated` did not work because it crashes before it reaches pypy

questions:

- is there a way to upgrade all packages that does not depend on a specific port (eigen in my case)
- or atleast: is there a way to get a list of all ports that depends (or does not depend) on a specific port

NB: I have uninstalled (I am an idiot) eigen, so I cannot do

```
sudo port -n upgrade outdated
# -n: don't upgrade dependencies (affects upgrade and install)
```

**Update**

what Vortexfive suggested should work:

```
sudo port upgrade outdated and not rdepof:eigen
```

however it dosent if you have already deleted eigen, so do not follow my example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To list the installed ports that depend on a specific port you can do `port list rdepof:eigen`.

To list the installed ports that do not depend on a specific port do `port list installed and not rdepof:eigen`.

Finally to update all ports that do not depend on a specific port do `sudo port upgrade outdated and not rdepof:eigen`.

I'm however not completely sure if this will work with the port (`eigen`) already uninstalled.

Comment: I assume you mean upgrade and not update... it dosen't work when I have already installed eigen unfortionatly, thanks anyways!, is there a way to force eigen to be compiled with libstdc++ instead of libc++?, because as fare as I can understand from "https://lists.macosforge.org/pipermail/macports-dev/2013-October/024715.html" that is why it can not be compile any longer :)

Comment: Indeed, upgrade instead of update. I have no idea how to force it to use libstdc++.

Comment: I mark you as best answer, it's not your fault that I I was a little to trigger happy :)